# Cell values not displayed correctly in Kendo UI Grid using custom DropDownList editor

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

The title may be confusing, but I had a bit of trouble explaining myself in a single sentence, so read on for a bit more detailed scenario.

I am trying to get a [Kendo UI DropDownList](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdownlist/index) working correctly when used as an editor in a [Kendo UI Grid](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/index).

I've got the following @model in my view;

```js
{
  "DataItems": [
    { "Id": 1, "Name": "Foo", "Category": { "Id": 1 } },
    { "Id": 2, "Name": "Bar", "Category": { "Id": 2 } }
  ],
  "CategoryOptions": [
    { "Id": 1, "Name": "A" },
    { "Id": 2, "Name": "B" },
    { "Id": 3, "Name": "C" }
  ],
}
```

This is passed to my script, which upon initializing constructs the following data source and grid

```js
var gridDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data: _model.DataItems,
    schema: {
        model: {
            id: "Id",
            fields: {
                Id: { type: "number", editable: false, nullable: false },
                Name: { type: "string", validation: { required: true } },
                Category: { type: "object" },
            }
        },
    }
});
```

```js
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: _model.DataItems,
    columns: [
        { field: "Id", hidden: true },
        { field: "Name", width: "200px", title: "Name", },
        { field: "Category", title: "Category", editor: categoryDropDownList, template: "#= (Category != null && Category.Name !== null) ? Category.Name : ' ' #" },
        { command: "destroy", title: "&nbsp;"}
    ],
    toolbar: ["save", "cancel"],
    editable: true,
});
```

As you'll notice this grid is in-line editable, so clicking a cell will allow you to edit its contents. To edit `Category` I've added a custom editor (categoryDropDownList), which displays  _model.CategoryOptions.

```js
function categoryDropDownList(container, options) {
    $('<input data-value-field="Id" data-text-field="Name" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>').appendTo(container)
        .kendoDropDownList({
            dataSource: _model.CategoryOptions,
            dataValueField: "Id",
            dataTextField: "Name",
        });
}
```

This seems to work as expected.

You can click the `Category` cell, and select a value (A, B, or C). When you remove focus from that cell, a small flag appear in the top left corner to mark that cell as dirty, requiring you to save changes.

In my model the data item `Bar` has the category `B`. This means that upon loading the page, one would expect the cell value of `Category` to be `B`, as dictated by the template;

```
#= (Category != null && Category.Name !== null) ? Category.Name : ' ' #
```

Instead the text value in the Category cell is always empty, as if you hit the else of the ternary if template, which shouldn't be the case. It should be `B`.

However, if you click the cell to reveal the editor, you'll notice that the selected item in the DropDownList is actually B. Remove focus from the cell, and the value disappears with the DropDownList.

So it's as if the editor knows about the selected category, but the grid doesn't.

Does this make any sense for you guys?

Please leave a comment if you need a better explanation, more code etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's most likely because the editor template is asking for `Category.Name`, but it is null. The Category object in `DataItems` only has `Id` defined and has no idea that there is a relationship defined at `CategoryOptions`.

In your editor template, you can try something like this (or similar).

`#= (Category.Id !== null) ? $.grep(CategoryOptions, function(e){ return e.Id == Category.Id; })[0].Name : ' ' #`

Basically, return the Name of the object in `CategoryOptions` with an Id that matches the Category Id of `DataItem`.

---

If trying that does not work, you can try the [`column.values`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-columns.values) configuration that kendo supports. I imagine it would look something like this:

Your category column (no more template):

```
{ 
  field: "Category", 
  title: "Category", 
  editor: categoryDropDownList, 
  values: CategoryOptions      
},
```

Your data model would then need to be like this:

```
{
   "DataItems": [
       { "Id": 1, "Name": "Foo", "Category": 1 },
       { "Id": 2, "Name": "Bar", "Category": 2 }
   ],
   "CategoryOptions": [
       { "value": 1, "text": "A" },
       { "value": 2, "text": "B" },
       { "value": 3, "text": "C" }
   ],
}
```

---

**Adding function to kendo template context**

Declare your wrapper function inline as part of the editor template:

`"# var GetCategoryNameById = function(id){ return $.grep(CategoryOptions, function(e){ return e.Id == id; })[0].Name; }; # #= GetCategoryNameById(name) #"`

Kendo Template Hash Usage FYI:

`#= #` --> Render as HTML

`#  #` --> Arbitrary JS

Comment: You're spot on. I managed to get it working, but only by putting the grep logic in a function on `window` (making it globally accessible), as the template and _model.CategoryOptions execute in different contexts. I can then use `#: window.GetCategoryNameById(ConditionCategory.Id) #`. This works, but its pretty messy, so any ideas on how to access the variable from the template context would be appreciated, as JavaScript is pretty new to me.

Comment: @RuneVikestad Sorry, I had a feeling that it would be in different contexts, see my edit. Also, just be careful about the [0], I took the lazy way so my answer wouldn't be too long, but you should check if grep returns anything or you may get undefined or out of range exception.